# Copy latest artifact from one path to another

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to copy the latest *artifact* from one path to another using Artifactory API.

`POST /api/copy/{srcRepoKey}/{srcFilePath}?to=/{targetRepoKey}/{targetFilePath}[&dry=1][&suppressLayouts=0/1(default)][&failFast=0/1]`

Let's say I have a few *RPMs* named: `artifact-1.0-1.rpm`, `artifact-1.0-2.rpm` and `artifact-1.0-3.rpm`.

How to automatically copy the third artifact ?

Answer (score 2):

With the next release of Jfrog's CLI, planned in a couple of weeks, you'll be able to use SORT and LIMIT in the COPY command.
This will allow you to fetch only the latest item\artifact by SORTing by date and LIMITing to the result set to 1.

For now, you can use 2 sequential CURL commands to try and accomplish what you're after:

First use an [AQL SEARCH](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactoryQueryLanguage(AQL)) with you're SORT and LIMIT to retrieve the relevant item's path, and then use your COPY command with that path.

Note: the CLI's SORT and LIMIT feature has already been checked in to the CLI's dev branch, so if you wish to use a snapshot you can "download and build" the dev branch from [github](https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go#download-and-build-the-cli), and then test if the solution suites you.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can automatically copy all these artifacts in one statement. You can copy the folder but no regex or pattern can defined in copy command.